# how to choose Listeners for application performance testing in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am beginner for jmeter and I configured and run the script with help of Google materials but I am not sure about picking the right listener for the performance testing and metrics in the graph.

can you please guide me to add respective listeners and what kind of listeners to be added for Application server,database server,network server,web server testing?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is load testing tool and not a profiler. So there are no specific listeners for application server,DB server and all.

It works on http/https requests to produce load on target server. While scripting you can have as many listeners as you want to verify the script correctness and sample test runs.
But while actual load test minimal no. of listeners should be used. Listeners are for presenting the data which are cpu,memory intensive especially view results tree, view results table etc. should be avoided in actual load test.

Test should be carried out in non-ui mode for heavy load generation. Please have a look at `ctrl+H` (help, press `ctrl+h` on any component and this will show help) for all components available in JMeter from JMeter. Then probably you should be able to decide which ones are best for you.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank your so much for your valuable reply, in my point every listeners will show data and will display result, the thing is how to explain the memory,cpu,disk usage,throughput, response time of the current page from the graph

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor server-side components health the best option is using [PerfMon](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) extension available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/). You can collect different performance metrics like:

- CPU usage
- RAM usage
- Network IO
- Disk IO

In regards to JMeter bundled listeners: you can use all of them, but **after** tests execution. All the listeners are able to read .jtl results file and populate tables, graphs, etc. from it. For more recommendations see [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide

Comment: @Dmitri can I get your personal/professional ID (gmail,linkedin) If possible?